# Android: ExpandableListView and context menus

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an app utilizing **ExpandableListView**.
I use a subclass of **BaseExpandableListAdapter** to provide data to my **ExpandableListView**.

Then I try to add context menus to this view, but these menus should be different for group an child items in the expandable list. So in my adapter's **getChildView** and **getGroupView** I call **setOnCreateContextMenuListener** like this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(TestActivity.this);;
textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());      
textView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                      ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        TestActivity.this.onCreateChildContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
      }
    });
return textView;
```

**TestActivity.this.onCreateChildContextMenu** simply adds a few string to menu.

The problem:
This works quite fine - context menu appears and works as expected but group item cannot be expanded anymore. It simply ignores short clicks. I've checked - as expected the textView becomes isLongClickable() after this line but it remains not isClickable() - so I cannot see how this context menu callback can affect short click functionality.
I've solved this problem for me by adding this listener at the whole ExpandableListView and then patching the menu for children. But it looks ugly. Do I miss something?

Thanks.

Comment: I've found better solution - to use      registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView()); in my ExpandableListActivity and check if it is a group or a child by calling ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(). But anyway I don't understand described behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I found new:
in getChildView:

```
convertView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                String menuItems[];
                menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contextmenu);
                menu.setHeaderTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.sms_select));
                for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
                }
            }
});
```

and :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
    }
```